# Query first five requests for companies using sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to list only the first five requests for companies from my database. I have two tables named as Request and Company. There could be any amount of requests for a given company. But, I need to query and list only the first 5 requests of all the companies in my database.

```
select top 5 *
from Request as r 
    INNER JOIN Company c
    ON r.Company_id=c.Company_ID
```

I have done the above query but it is returning only the first five from the table not the first five of all members. How can I correct my query?

Comment: You need to specify ORDER BY so Sql Server knows which rows you want. So, if there is a date_column, and you want to return first 5 by date, add `order by date_column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for the top 5 requests for each company that exists in your Company table. In that case, you can `rank()` each request by company in a subselect and then select where the rank is `<= 5`:

```
select company_id, request_id
from
    ( select c.company_id, r.request_id, rank() over (partition by c.company_id order by request_id) as Rank
    from request r
    inner join company c on
        r.company_id = c.company_id
    ) ranked
where rank <= 5
```

Comment: You need to qualify the `company_id` in the partition statement as in `partition by c.company_id`.  Otherwise, you get an ambiguous column error.  (That's what I'm getting in sqlfiddle.)

Answer (score 2):

```
    With r 
    as
    (select  *, row_number() over(partition by Company_id order by RequestDate) as rown
    from Request as)
    Select *
from r join Company c on c.Company_id=r.Company_id
    Where rown<=5
```

Comment: @Josh, this is what you want. It's called partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ORDER BY the field which determines 'firstness'.  Probably something like:

ORDER BY r.RequestDate

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH companyrecords 
     AS (SELECT Company.*, 
                Row_number() OVER (partition BY r.Company_id ORDER BY 
                r.Company_id 
                ASC) 
                   AS 
                RowNumber 
         FROM   Request AS r 
                INNER JOIN Company c 
                  ON r.Company_id = c.Company_ID) 
SELECT * 
FROM   companyrecords 
WHERE  RowNumber <= 5
```